# How to get a process FriendlyName from process from instance name?

Tags: c#, windows, process

I have a following program code:

```
var category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Process", _server.Name);
var names = category.GetInstanceNames();
```

where `_server.Name` is a piece of data from the database representing `Environment.MachineName` for a computer somewhere on the network. 
Is there a way to get a FriendlyName for the process based on a given instance name? 
Note: it must be done remotely for computers in the local network...